# ERROR The "html" reporter does not exist. Check the reporter parameter for errors

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am running with **ERROR The "html" reporter does not exist. Check the reporter parameter for errors.** error while running test using testcafe. Can you please let me know what I can do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Please check that you have installed the testcafe-reporter-html npm package.
To install it use the following command:

```
npm install testcafe-reporter-html
```

If this does not help, perhaps, the reporter throws an error that was not added to the console output.
We already have a similar request for adding the information from the original error to the console output: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6437
This will be implemented in one of the future releases.

Answer (score 1):

TestCafe has these reporters built in: https://testcafe.io/documentation/402825/guides/concepts/reporters#header

All others would need to be installed via npm and imported into the project.

Answer (score -1):

Try to install npm globally, Issue will resolve

npm install -g testcafe-reporter-html

Source : https://testcafe.io/documentation/402811/guides/extend-testcafe/install-plugins